# Why I can't see my logo appear Homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, photo, gif

This is website I am working on abraham-accountants.co.uk. However the logo appear on all the web pages but not on the homepage.

This php code I used to add logo in and uploaded logo file to ftp server.

```
// Display Site Title

add_action( 'smartline_site_title', 'smartline_display_site_title' );

function smartline_display_site_title() { ?>

<div class='my-logo'>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/AA.gif">
</div>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"
    title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" 
    rel="home">

<h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>

</a>

<?php

}
```

This was done on template-tag php file for smartline lite theme.

Answer (score 1):

try this code by adding to functions.php in your themes folder,

```
function my_logo() {
echo '<style type="text/css">
h1 a { background-image:url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/your-logo.png) !important; }
</style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_logo');
```

Comment: where about do i add in the functions.php section

Comment: any where , may be at the bottom of the file.

Comment: function my_logo() {
echo '<style type="text/css">
h1 a { background-image:url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/AA.gif) !important; }
</style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_logo');

Comment: try these steps, https://tutorials4.wordpress.com/how-to-change-logo-of-your-wordpress-template/

Comment: It don't allow me to do them options, however when i log-in to wordpress website the logo appear on homepage when  i sign out the logo disappear. the logo shows on all of the pages expect homepage.

Comment: go to Settings -> Reading -> Select "Front page displays a static page" and then select "Home" from the dropdown menu to edit the home page, and paste the logo url , by gettting the logo url from other page view source

Comment: Thank you for that, how to i edit the home page from drop-down menu.

Comment: <div class="my-logo">                                                                                      <img src="http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/wpcontent/themes/smartline-lite/images/AA.gif">                                                                                              This what it shows for other pages source.

Comment: do this way, login to website admin, appearance->theme editor, on right side you see list of files, select one of the files may be index.php or home.php which is the home page,once you click on the file link open the file in the beside editor,then you can page the logo code at proper place

Comment: where do paste in index.php or home.php file

Comment: in the header check for logo css, and paste it

Comment: under <?php get_header(); ?>

Comment: if you see <?php get_header(); ?>,then it not the home page. sorry, try to open the header file header.php to see the logo related code

Comment: I have open up header file where do i paste it in

Comment: go to <header> tag and search for logo related css

Comment: <header id="header" class="clearfix" role="banner">

   <div id="logo" class="clearfix">
   
    <?php do_action('smartline_site_title'); ?>
    
    <?php // Display Tagline on header if activated
    if ( isset($theme_options['header_tagline']) and $theme_options['header_tagline'] == true ) : ?>   
     <h2 class="site-description"><?php echo bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
   
   </div>
   
   <div id="header-content" class="clearfix">
    <?php get_template_part('inc/header-content'); ?>
   </div>

Comment: paste the logo image code after <div id="logo" class="clearfix"> and save it

Comment: <div id="logo" class="clearfix">
   <img src="http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/wp-content/themes/smartline-lite/images/AA.gif">                                                    This what i did noting happens or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: <div class="my-logo">
<img src="http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/wp-content/themes/smartline-lite/images/AA.gif">
</div>                                                                                                               I tried this aswell same result happen.

Comment: put src="http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/wp-content/themes/smartline-lite/images/AA.gif"

Comment: <src="http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/wp-content/themes/smartline-lite/images/AA.gif">                                                                                                 I did added http:// still nothing happen i'm missing something out.

Comment: the logo is appearing on the homepage